# Text disappears behind image slidebar

Tags: html

**I have a problem: I made a slidebar that shows the pictures. Now I want to continue underneath by putting text and other things on the page, but if I try to just insert a text below, for example, the text will not be written under the slideshow but under the slideshow.
Here is the code I hope you can help me.**

```css
div.slider {
    display: flex;
    width: 92%;
    height: 750px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
div.slider > * {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    animation: slide 12s infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.slide:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0%;
    animation-delay: -1s;
    background-image: url(https://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-7/data/images/amsterdam.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
div.slide:nth-child(2) {
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    background-image: url(https://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-7/data/images/barpark.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
div.slide:nth-child(3) {
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    background-image: url(https://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-7/data/images/florence.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
div.slide:nth-child(4) {
    left: 100%;
    animation-delay: 8s;
    background-image: url(https://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-7/data/images/gate.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
div.slide p {
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    color: #fff
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% { left: 100%; width: 100%;}
    5% { left: 0%;}
    25% { left: 0%;}
    30% { left: -100%; width: 100%;}
    30.0001% { left: -100%; width: 0%;}
    100% { left: 100%; width: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
      <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide"><p>Slide1</p></div>
          <div class="slide"><p>Slide2</p></div>
          <div class="slide"><p>Slide3</p></div>
          <div class="slide"><p>Slide4</p></div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p>Text that should appear under the slideshow.</p>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is some how vague, could you prepare a picture of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position` of `div.slider` to `relative`